# Herstein Chapter 2 Exercise (Potential Abuse of Cancellation Property)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

**Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that whenever $Ha\neq Hb$ then $aH \neq bH$. Prove that $gHg^{-1} \subset H$.**

Suppose that $aH=bH$. Then for some $h \in H$ we have $ah=bh$ which implies that $a=b$ (by the cancellation property) so we have that $Ha=Hb=Ha$ and then left multiplication by $a^{-1}$ gives us (This is where I might be abusing cancellation law)
$$
a^{-1}Ha=a^{-1}Ha=H
$$
which gives us
$$
a(a^{-1}Ha)a^{-1}=aHa^{-1}=H
$$
so $H$ is abelian and it follows that for any $g \in G$ we have that $g^{-1}Hg=H$ so $gHg^{-1} \subset H$

Something feels "off" about this proof though. Can someone point out where I might have gone astray?

Comment: $aH = bH$ does not imply that $ah = bh$ for any $h \in H$. E.g. $1+\mathbb Z = 2 + \mathbb Z$, but certainly $1 \neq 2$.

Comment: Just to add to kahen's comment, $aH = bH$ actually implies for any $h\in H$, there exists $h'\in H$ (maybe $h'\neq h$!) such that $ah = bh'$.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean exactly. However there has to be at least *one* $h \in H$ such that $ah=bh$ like $ae=be \implies a=b$, right? I'm pretty new to this way of thinking so please bare with me but the point seems to be that given two cosets of a subgroup $H$ you can only have that they are the same set or that they aren't the same set.

Comment: I edited to fix this but is the rest of the reasoning sound?

Comment: @BadStudent "given two cosets of a subgroup $H$ you can only have that they are the same set or that they aren't the same set" That's... tautologically true. What is more interesting (and perhaps that's what you meant?) is that they are disjoint, so if $aH\neq bH$, then they have no common element, i.e. $aH\cap bH=\emptyset$.

Comment: Moreover, you haven't corrected the error mentioned by kahen; and the rest of your reasoning doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: @ArnaudD. In light of kahens comment saying that since $H$ is a subgroup then $e \in H$ and if $aH=bH$ then $ae=be \implies a=b$ since $ae, be \in aH=bH$. Then once I establish that, it follows that Ha=Hb and then I just multiply on the left by $a^{-1}$ to show that $a^{-1}Ha=b^{-1}Hb=a^{-1}Ha=H$ by the cancellation law which shows that $H$ is abelian which is sufficient to prove that $gHg^{-1} =H$, right?

Comment: @BadStudent $aH=bH$ only means that they are the same subset of $G$; equivalently, for every $h\in H$, $ah\in bH$ and $bh\in aH$, which means that $ah=bh'$ and $bh=ah''$ for some $h',h''\in H$. But it certainly does not mean that every two elements of $aH$ and $bH$ are equal! This would imply that every two elements of $aH$ are equal, and thus that $H$ is trivial!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1**

> Assume there is $g \in G$ such that $g H g^{-1} \not\subset H$.

**Hint 2**

> So there are $g \in G$ and $h \in H$ such that $g h g^{-1} \notin H$, or $g h \notin H g$.

**Hint 3**

> So $H (g h) \ne H g$.

Comment: So basically if I assume that $gHg^{-1}$ isn't a subset of $H$ then I just show that $Hg$ isn't a subgroup?

Comment: No, you get two elements $a, b$ such that $H a \ne H b$, whereas...